# Problemas com os ifs no react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Boa tarde! Tenho um código em javascript de uma aplicação em react, mas por algum motivo a minha IDE está acusando um erro numa linha em que se encontra um `else` de um `if`, mas não sei como resolver-lo!

O erro encontra-se em laranja.

Provavelmente o erro seja muito estúpido, mas sou novo em javascript!

```
<View style={styles.form}>
    { showBox ? colorBox == "warm" ? <View style={styles.boxWarm}><Text style={styles.boxWarmText}>{boxText}</Text></View> : colorBox == "error" ? 
        <View style={styles.boxError}><Text style={styles.boxWarmText}>{boxText}</Text></View> : <View style={styles.boxOk}><Text style={styles.boxWarmText}>{boxText}</Text></View> : null }
    { showContent ?
        <Text style={styles.label}>INSIRA A NOVA PASSWORD:</Text>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            textContentType="password"
            placeholder="Introduza a nova password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholderTextColor="#999"
            value={newPass}
            ref={(input) => this.newpass = input}
            onChangeText={pass => hideInfoDuringTyping(pass, "newpass") }
            onSubmitEditing={() => this.renewpass.focus()}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>INSIRA A NOVA PASSWORD:</Text>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            textContentType="password"
            placeholder="Introduza novamente a nova password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholderTextColor="#999"
            value={renewpass}
            ref={(input) => this.renewpass = input}
            onChangeText={pass => hideInfoDuringTyping(pass, "renewpass") }
            onSubmitEditing={handleRecover}
        />
```

> : null }

```
        { showInfo ? 
            <Text style={colorInfo == "warm" ? styles.infoWarm : colorInfo == "error" ? styles.infoError : styles.infoOk }>{infoText}</Text> : null }
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={handleRecover} style={styles.buttonMain}><Text style={styles.buttonTextMain}>Alterar a password</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={startSession} style={styles.buttonSecundary}><Text style={styles.buttonTextSecundary}>{btnTxt}</Text></TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pois no `javascript react` não é aceito mais de uma tag como retorno.

ou seja:

isso aqui pode ser feito:

```
{ showContent ?
<View>
 <Text style={styles.label}>INSIRA A NOVA PASSWORD:</Text>
 <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    textContentType="password"
    placeholder="Introduza a nova password"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    placeholderTextColor="#999"
    value={newPass}
    ref={(input) => this.newpass = input}
    onChangeText={pass => hideInfoDuringTyping(pass, "newpass") }
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.renewpass.focus()}
 />
 ...
</View>
: null }
```

pois o retorno da condição é apenas uma `tag`, no caso `View`, o exemplo abaixo mostra um erro ao retornar duas tags ao inves de uma encapsulando elas.

```
{ showContent && <Text>Oi</Text><Text>Tomas</Text> : null }
```

uma dica, você pode usar `&&` para retornar uma condição caso verdadeiro, eliminando o `: null` do seu código ex:

```
{ showContent &&
  <View>
   <Text style={styles.label}>INSIRA A NOVA PASSWORD:</Text>
    <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       textContentType="password"
       placeholder="Introduza a nova password"
       secureTextEntry={true}
       placeholderTextColor="#999"
       value={newPass}
       ref={(input) => this.newpass = input}
       onChangeText={pass => hideInfoDuringTyping(pass, "newpass") }
       onSubmitEditing={() => this.renewpass.focus()}
    />
    ...
  </View> 
}
```